how to solve the incomplete type error in struct declaration
I have a file
#include <stdint.h>

// starting at 0xFFFFFFFF going upwards
uint32_t stackpointers[32];

typedef enum {
    READY, BUSY, DONE
}State;

struct TCB_entry {
    struct Thread thread;
    // thread 0 is the idle thread
    State state;
};


struct Thread {
    uint32_t r0_r12[13];
    uint32_t lr;
    uint32_t sp;
    uint32_t PC;
    uint32_t CPSR;
};

struct TCB_entry TCB[32];

struct Thread* get_thread(struct Thread* thread);

struct Thread init_thread();

void setup_TCB();

void print_thread_context(struct Thread* thread);

and it gives an incomplete type error in the TCB_entry struct for thread. I only read posts on recursive structs with incomplete types but this is not the case. I tried to initialise the thread like so struct Thread thread = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},0,0,0,0} but I got even more errors!

I cannot reproduce the problem when I copy both structure definitions into a single file. After adding the required #include <stdint.h>, I only get an error about the missing State. Please [edit] your question and convert your code snippets to a [mre], i.e. preferably a single file we can compile to reproduce the problem.

Where is the Thread structure defined? Where is the TCB_Entry structure defined? Are they defined in different header files? Is the Thread header file included in the header file where you define TCB_Entry? Are you perhaps including the header file for TCB_Entry into the header file for Thread?

Assuming State is defined as typedef int State; (just a wile guess, you didn't tell us what State actually is), this compiles fine.

Oh by the way, when you [edit] your question, also copy-paste the full and complete build-log into the question. We would very much like to see the actual errors you get.

@Bodo I edited the question so you can see the context.

Definition order matters. If you want to use a structure, you must define it before you use it.

IOW: move the declaration of struct Thread before the declaration of struct TCB_entry.

If you're just going to initialize everything with 0, struct Thread thread = {0};

The order of the definition matters.
struct TCB_entry has a field of type struct Thread, but that type has not been defined at that point.
Place the definition of struct Thread before the definition of struct TCB_entry.
